# Why is that the Azure Web Application Firewall doesnot support for IPv6 IP address space?

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-web-app-firewall

I was trying to configure WAF with IPv6 address space for my application. But when I try to assign my IPv6 it says the following error message. How can I configure IPv6 with the WAF ?

[image: WAF-IPv6]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to public IP address version [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-arm#ip-address-version) in Azure.

> Public IP addresses are created with an IPv4 or IPv6 address. Public
>   IPv6 addresses can **only** be assigned to **Internet-facing load balancers**.

So you could not assign a public Ipv6 address with an Azure Application Gateway, it only supports in Azure public-facing load balancer.